# Prove that $a\geq0$, when $f(x)=x^{3}+ax$ is (strictly) increasing.

Tags: functions, special-functions

I need help with proving that $a\geq0$, when $f(x)=x^{3}+ax$ is (strictly) increasing.

Edit: Without using derivatives.

Comment: Hint. Look at the derivative, which must be always positive. What happens near $0$?

Comment: The derivative $3x^2+a$ is strictly positive?

Comment: I think you made a mistake with your question, check if $a > 0$ or if $a \ge 0$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the derivative of $f$.

Comment: I don't know derivatives yet. My teacher meant different way of proving that one.

Answer (score 0):

If a function $f(x)$ is strictly increasing then $f'(x) > 0 \forall x$

$$f'(x) = 3x^2 + a$$

Now assuming you meant $a>0$ we know that $f'(x) >0$ for all $x$ as the smallest $x^2$ can be is $0$ and adding $a$ makes $f'(x)>0 \forall x$

Answer (score 0):

Prove that $$f(x_1)>f(x_2)\iff (x_1^3-x_2^3)+a(x_1-x_2)>0$$ where $x_1>x_2$ and $a\geq 0$ and if $a<0$ you have that $f(x)=0$ when $x=0$ or $x=\sqrt{-a}$ which violates the strictness,also since $\frac{\sqrt{-a}}{2}>0$ you could also take $f(\frac{\sqrt{-a}}{2})=\frac{7a\sqrt{-a}}{8}<0$ and $f(0)=0$

Comment: I can prove that, but does that change anything?

Comment: @deve343 This is the definition of a strictly increasing function,if for every $x_1>x_2$ you have that $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$.Take a look at [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StrictlyIncreasingFunction.html) for example

Comment: I know, but I have to prove that $a\geq0$, not that $f$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: @deve343 Take a look at my edit,is this okay?

Comment: Could you explain it a bit? How did you get $f(0)=f(\sqrt{-a})$ ?

Comment: @deve343 $f(x)=x(x^2+a)$ from this $f(x)=0$ if $x=0$ or if $x=\sqrt{-a}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint for the revised question ("without using derivatives").

Essentially, you can mimic what the derivative would tell you for values of $x$ near $0$. If $a$ were negative then $f(x) = x^2(x+a)$ would be decreasing for some range of values of $x$ you should be able to figure out.

Comment: Okay, so if $a=-1$, then $f(0)=0$ and $f(\frac{1}{2})=-0.125$. But $x^{2}(x+a)\neq x^{3}+ax$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $x^3+ax$ is odd. Therefore, if it is strictly increasing, it must take values in the first and third quadrant only.

Write $x^3+ax = x (x^2+a)$ as a product of two terms and consider its sign for $x > 0$. If $a < 0$, $x^2+a < 0$ for $|x|< \sqrt{-a}$ and thus $x (x^2+a) < 0$ for $0<x<\sqrt{-a}$, which contradicts the above. Hence $a \ge 0$.

Comment: $x^3 + ax = x(x^2+a)$, not $x^2(x+a)$.

Comment: @Eff: ouch. Thank you for spotting the error. I revised the argument using the right expression, and it comes out cleaner.

Comment: I agree with the second part. First one, though... If a function is odd, it doesn't imply it is strictly increasing, take sin(x) as an example.

Comment: @deve343: Yes, but the assumption that $x^3+ax$ is strictly increasing is made as part of your question (you wrote "when it is increasing"). I am pointing out that the function is odd, and then drawing the consequences of assuming that it is odd.